# Exporting dates as dates

Tags: apache-poi, jmesa

We're currently using JMesa on a project to show HTML tables and exporting this data to Excel files.

For date columns we use this:

```
Column date = new Column("source.date").cellEditor(new DateCellEditor(DateUtil.DD_MM_YYYY));
```

However, this exports that data as text, which results in our users not being able to sort this column correctly in Excel. Is there a possiblity to tell JMesa to format this column as a date ?

Also, is it possible to tell JMesa to automatically set the width of the columns (it's possible in POI).

We're currently using JMesa 3.0.0

Comment: It would also be great to know how to configure the Excel date format because I suppose it'll go by default for some kind of YYYY/MM/DD format whereas we would like to have DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: Were u able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, not yet. The request for this feature was delayed so we didn't investigate any further.